# How to display view using ng-view in AngularJS 1?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I am trying to show a view from a directory called views in Angular 1.6. I am using the ng-view directive. The views that I want to show are **home.html** and **directory.html**

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="" ng-app="myNinjaApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>TheNetNinja Angular Playlist</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Angular JS 1 Lib should be inserted in the head -->
        <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <header ng-include src="'header.html'"></header>

        <main ng-view></main>


    </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<h1>Homepage</h1>
```

directory.html

```
<div class="content">
    <div ng-controller="NinjaController">
        <p>{{message}}</p>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="ninja in ninjas">{{ninja}}</li>
        </ul>

        <button ng-click="order = 'name'">Order by Name</button>
        <button ng-click="order = 'belt'">Order by Belt</button>

        <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for a ninja" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="ninja in ninjaP | orderBy: order | filter:search"  ng-show="ninja.available">
                <img ng-src="{{ninja.thumb}}" style="margin: -12px 10px 0 0; float: left; width: 50px;" ng-show="ninja.thumb">
                <h3>{{ninja.name}} - {{ninja.rate | currency: '£'}}</h3>

                <div class="remove" ng-click="removeNinja(ninja)">x</div>

                <span class="belt" style="background: {{ninja.belt}}">{{ninja.belt}} belt</span>
            </li>
        </ul>



    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myNinjaApp = angular.module('myNinjaApp', ['ngRoute']);


myNinjaApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/directory', {
            templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
            controller: 'NinjaController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

}]);
```

When I go to /home or / directory, it does not display the proper content.

I am prompted with "**The requested URL /angular-js-playlist/home was not found on this server.**"

ng-view directive seems like not grabbing the content

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.6 default hash-prefix used for $location is changed from emty to bang ('' to !). If you dont want this hash prefix add this

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

config settings

```
myNinjaApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/directory', {
        templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
        controller: 'NinjaController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

}]);
```

refer : [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52)

Comment: great answer. do i also need to include something in the var myNinjaApp = angular.module('myNinjaApp', ['ngRoute']); ? because i also see that you added $locationProvider

Comment: No need. inject '$locationProvider' in myNinjaApp.config()

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you dont have href to go it .
Add it in what ever you want . And in directory.html you dont need write `ng-controller="NinjaController"` .  Or if you have it 
routes in Angular 1.6 changed from `#/myUrl` to `#!/myUrl`

You should change your ref to.

```
<a href="#!/home">Home</a>
```

And I recommend you  use ui-router instead ngRouter . It flexible and better than ngRouter

Answer (score 1):

Just go through this link it will give you informations on how to use ng-view using ngroute

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView